# I was entering data into an sql table then this errors occurred

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SQL> insert into sacco values(5647899,'Gabriel Omondi',28-jul-11,'male','kisumu',45000);
values(5647899,'Gabriel Omondi',28-jul-11,'male','kisumu',45000)
                               *
```

ERROR on line 2:

> ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Comment: you may need to put 28-jul-11 in quotes

Answer (score 4):

```sql
insert into sacco
values(5647899,'Gabriel Omondi',28-jul-11,'male','kisumu',45000);
```

`28-jul-11` is being parsed as the number `28` then subtract `-` the column `jul` then subtract `-` the number `11`.

You need to use single quotes to show it is a text literal:

```sql
insert into sacco
values(5647899,'Gabriel Omondi','28-jul-11','male','kisumu',45000);
```

However, while it will work, that is bad practice as you are relying on an implicit cast from a string to a date. A **better** solution is to use a date literal:

```sql
insert into sacco
values(5647899,'Gabriel Omondi', DATE '2011-07-28','male','kisumu',45000);
```

Comment: of course that is assuming that the receiving column is defined as a DATE.  Of course, if the table is properly designed, it would be defined as a DATE, but we don't know that it is, so a caveat is called for.